# SQL advice about inner select and join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some sort of debate with a colleague about a piece of sql. In a project, I wrote something like this :

```
update MyTable
set field1 = (select count(distinct blabla)
              from anotherTable t
              inner join againAnotherTable t2 on t2.fk = t1.pk
              where t2.fk = MyTable.fk)
```

after some unitTests, the field "field1" of MyTable is properly populated with valid values. My colleague is telling me that I got lucky because the link I do inside the inner query (t2.fk = MyTable.fk) is inconsistent and I might have some error sometimes and update the wrong line or update the whole table. Instead I should put a join after the end of the parenthesis

Did I miss something ? Is there indeed a huge mistake on my side ?

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks fine to me.

Do note that it does update the entire table because there is no `where` clause (or other filtering) for the `update`.  Unmatched rows will have a value of `0`.  I don't know if that is what you intend.

Of course, this all depends on whether `t2.fk = MyTable.fk` is the logic you really want.  I don't know what "inconsistent" would mean in this case.

I don't see how changing the data could result in an *error*.  You might get unexpected values.  For instance, if you intend for `NULL` values of `fk` to match, they won't.  If there are no matches, then you'll get `0`.  The may not be the *correct* result (based on the logic you intend), but the query would be doing something sensible.

Comment: And in the future (and perhaps now), always ask your colleague for a proof and an explanation. Quite often, you will find that none can be produced - and you can draw your own conclusions from that fact. As Gordon indicates, the  only consideration in this example is that your query will update every row in the table. Sometimes we only want to update those rows where there is a "match" in the other tables.Using a join updates only matching rows - something that the other posters did not explain well.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok for this query if you wanted to actually update it that way, but if you want to update fields with join, and include the table being updated, do not write it like that.

Your colleague is trying to make sure that you write safer update queries in future. He does not want you to miss `where t2.fk = MyTable.fk` someday, in the sub-query. That would update the table incorrectly.

In that case then, write it like shown below,

```
update a set a.field1 = b.value 
  FROM MyTable a INNER JOIN anotherTable b ON a.condition1 = b.condition2
     INNER JOIN yetAnotherTable c ON a.condition1 = c.condition2
```

> So, you should change your update query to something like below

```
update a
set field1 = count(distinct blabla) 
FROM anotherTable b INNER JOIN againAnotherTable t2 on t2.fk = t1.pk 
INNER JOIN MyTable a ON t2.fk = MyTable.fk
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @field1 datatype 

set @field1 = (select count(distinct blabla)
          from anotherTable t
          inner join againAnotherTable t2 on t2.fk = t1.pk
          where t2.fk = MyTable.fk)

update table set column=@field1 where id=''
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Sure @Toby Speight